# Larabook tests error - cannot login user

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have gone through the [Larabook series at Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/build-a-laravel-app-from-scratch) but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. My code is working perfectly in the browser but my functional tests are failing because the user is not logged in. This is the SignUpTest and it passes until the last bit 
`$I->assertTrue(Auth::check());`

```
$I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
$I->am('guest');
$I->wantTo('sign up for a Larabook account');

$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->click('Sign Up!');
$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/register');

$I->fillfield('Username:', 'JohnDoe');
$I->fillfield('Email:', 'john@example.com');
$I->fillfield('Password:', 'demo');
$I->fillfield('Password Confirmation:', 'demo');
$I->click('Sign Up');

$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('');
$I->see('Welcome to Larabook');
$I->seeRecord('users', [
    'username' => 'JohnDoe'
]);


$I->assertTrue(Auth::check());
```

The problem is that it does not log in the user so `Auth::check()` returns false. I followed Jeffery to the letter and I can't figure out why it is not working.

For the SignInCept, I have the same issue

```
$I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
$I->am('a larabook member');
$I->wantTo('login to my larabook account');

$I->signIn();
$I->seeInCurrentUrl('/statuses');
$I->see('Post a status');
$I->assertTrue(Auth::check());
```

The signIn method

```
public function signIn()
    {
        $email = 'foo@example.com';
        $username = 'Foobar';
        $password = 'foo';

        $this->haveAnAccount(compact('email', 'username', 'password'));

        $I = $this->getModule('Laravel4');

        $I->amOnPage('/login');
        $I->fillField('email', $email);
        $I->fillField('password', $password);
        $I->click('Sign In');
    }
```

The tests fail at the assertTrue because again, it takes in the credentials, even goes to the status url but somehow the user is not logged in yet.

All my functional tests fail whenever I call the signIn method. Can anyone please tell me why it is not Logging in a user?

Comment: Are you sure that `Auth::check()` is the method you should be calling here? I have never been working with Laravel, so I may be wrong, but it looks like general method for checking auth, within context of the current app. In this case that would be env in which you run tests, not the env you are testing. I would expect tested env to be encapsulated and separated. That's the way how it works in other frameworks.

Comment: That is what the tutorial uses but I also used the laravel4 module testing method of checking the authenticated user `$I->seeAuthentication();` but it also throws an error that there is no authenticated user. My problem is that the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that by default in `app\config\testing\session.php` the driver is set to `array` which means that no persistence of data occurs. So the solution is to change this to either `database` or`cookie` or any of the ones provided in the php_doc section. In my case I used `cookie` and all my tests passed.